# Understanding the size of my structure

Tags: c, struct, sizeof

My code:

```
typedef struct {
    int sizeOfMyIntArray;
    int* myIntArray;
    float someFloat;
} my_struct_foo;

int main() {
    printf("The size of float is: %d\n", sizeof(float));
    printf("The size of int is: %d\n", sizeof(int));
    printf("The size of int* is: %d\n", sizeof(int*));
    printf("The size of my_struct_foo is: %d\n", sizeof(my_struct_foo));
    return 0;
}
```

I'd imagine that this is very simple. Although, I am a bit surprised by the resulting output of this program...

```
The size of float is: 4
The size of int is: 4
The size of int* is: 8
The size of my_struct_foo is: 24
```

I have one float, one int, and one pointer-to-an-int. In my head I am thinking: 4 + 4 + 8 = 16...not 24. Why is the size of my structure 24 instead of 16?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alignment and padding. The `int*` should be aligned on an eight-byte boundary, so the compiler inserts four bytes of padding between the `int` and the pointer, and after (or before) the `float` to make the size of the struct a multiple of the pointer size and have the pointer correctly aligned.

If you reorder the members,

```
typedef struct {
    int sizeOfMyIntArray;
    float someFloat;
    int* myIntArray;
} my_struct_foo;
```

the pointer would be correctly aligned without any padding, so the size of the struct would (very probably, the compiler is allowed to add padding even if it is not needed, but I know of none that does) be 16.

Comment: This fixes the problem. However, when I add an additional float* to the structure it makes the size of the structure 32 bytes. This is again resolved by moving the float* to the end of the structure. However, it is odd to me that this should be a problem; the addition of the float* to the structure should make the structure 24 bytes (a multiple of 8).

Comment: Where do you add the `float*`? If you add it in a place where the sum of the sizes and necessary padding for the previous members is a multiple of eight, it should only increase the struct size by 8. If, in the reordered struct, you add it between the `int` and the `float`, the situation is the same as before, without padding, it would not be eight-byte aligned, so padding would be added.